# Why traction vector is zero?

Tags: stress-energy-momentum-tensor, continuum-mechanics

I'm reading a book about continuum mechanics and I can't understand why traction vector depends on orientation. Here is an extract from the book:

> [image]
>
> [image]

As far as I understand no matter what orientation you make a cut the forces acting on the system do not change. So the F in invariant. Now the author says that if you do a cut perpendicular to a truss then you will see that a traction vector $t(i)$ (not a coordinate vector) acting along x axis (that is along i cut normal). But if you make a cut in the same point perpendicular to x axis then traction dissapears suddenly!!! This is absurd! the traction will be tangential to the new cut.

Help me. I see similar claims by many other authors and I don't understand how this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I understand no matter what orientation you make a cut the
>   forces acting on the system do not change.

I think this is your main point of confusion. The force does depend on where you make the cut. For example, imagine you are holding two ropes, one in each hand, and people pull equally on the ropes in opposite directions. Now what is the force on you? It is zero. But what happens to the force on you if we cut one of the ropes? The force does not stay the same. Instead you will find that if you cut the rope on your right, then you will be pulled to the left. Meanwhile if you cut the rope on the right, you will be pulled to the left. So we see that where you make the cut does affect the forces on the system.

Now let's consider a slightly more complicated example where you additionally have ropes pulling you forward and backward. Now if you just cut the rope pulling you forward you will be pulled backward, and if you just cut the rope pulling you backward, you will be pulled forward.

The difference between cutting the rope to your left and cutting the rope in front of you corresponds to a difference in the orientation of the cut. Thus the orientation of the cut does affect the direction of the resulting force.

If we translate the books example into this language, we would imagine a grid of people who have ropes attached to them in all four directions, but only the left and right ropes have tension; the forward and backward are just loose. Now if we go in and make a big cut through this network cutting along the "$y$" direction as shown in the original picture, then we are cutting ropes that have tension in them, so the people at the surface where the cut was made feel an uncompensated tension away from the surface, and they will be pulled away. Thus there is a non-zero traction force. Now if instead we cut in the "$x$" direction, we are cutting ropes that don't have tension in them, so the force on each person remains zero and so there is no traction force.

Comment: You analogy I perfectly understand. But I was talking about this:
If you make a cut perpendicular to the rope then, yes, the force will be normal to the surface of the cut and will be a pulling force. But when you make a cut parallel to the rope the the same force which was pulling perpendicula cut now "shears" parralel cut. So, the SAME force normal to one cut and tangental to the other.

Comment: @coobit I don't understand the above scenario. Let's think about a single guy who has a rope attached to front and back with no tension and a rope pulling to his right and left with tension. Now which rope are you cutting and what are you saying the resulting force should be?

Comment: As I cut from front to back there will be normal stress on the guy (pulling from left to right). Now as i cut from left to right there will be shear stress on the guy( the same stress which was normal for the first cut).

Comment: @coobit You might be confusing [stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor) and [force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force). The traction force is a force and not a stress. The traction force has to do with the force you would have to apply at a surface where a cut is made in order to maintain zero net force at that surface. So let's think about cutting the rope in front of the person. Now that rope had zero tension, so no force is need to keep zero net force on the person after the rope is cut.  ...

Comment: @coobit However, you are correct in thinking that the person still has a nonzero "$xx$" component of stress. On the other hand, consider what happens if the rope to the left is cut. Then you really do need to supply a force to keep the person stationary. In this case the traction force is non-zero.

Comment: ok, let me ask this in different setting: shear stress, tensile stress are they COMPONENTS (i.e. arithmetic vectors) or are they vectors i.e. real vectors physical)? I thought they were vectors. Physical vectors (traction) should never change no matter what cut I do, but compnents of that traction indeed should change.

Comment: @coobit I think it's clear that you are confused because you don't fully understand stress. The comments here aren't the proper place for an explanation of what the stress tensor is. You should go back and try to understand what the stress tensor is, and you get confused, then you should try to narrow down the exact thing that is confusing you and post  a separate question here.

Comment: @ NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs  I guess I've narrowed it down. Can you help with my question? see new post: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/275702/why-traction-vector-depends-on-surfacesection-orientration

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two identical bars with rectangular sections, and a identical forces applied to the ends of each bar. There are no "traction forces" at the surface along the length of the bars.

Now stick the two bars together, side by side.  Nothing changes. The stress in the bars is the same as before

Now cut them apart again. It would be "absurd" if sticking them together and cutting them apart magically created a traction force from nowhere.

Of course there is a traction force on cut a made  in *any* other direction, except the axial direction.

And for a *general* (triaxial) stress field in the bar there will be a non-zero traction force on a cut made in every possible direction.

The extract from the book that you quoted doesn't seem to mention that the constant uniaxial stress field in the example is a special (and simple) situation, not the general case.

Comment: So, let's have two long bars. Let there be pulling stress along each bar. Let's BEFORE sticking two bars together take a point at the surface of of one bar. Call it P. Now there is shear stress on this point (the cut is made through P and perpendicular to the long sude of the bar). Now, stick two bars together. Now we have a point P between bars and a crosssection along the two bars and.... Shear stress on P along the surface of contact of two bars.

Comment: I must be mistaken but I fail to see where.